# jquery datetimepicker 12 hours format with AM/PM

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

hi i want to add one more feature to my existing code that is 12 hours format with AM/PM this is also available in jsfiddle with link http://jsfiddle.net/8ztsjcos/3/ thank you

```
HTML 

 <link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<p>From:   <input type="text" id="to">  <div id="datepicker"></div> <p>To: <input type="text" id="from"><div id="datepicker1"></div>
JQUERY 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        timeFormat:'HH:mm',
        use24hours: false,
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes();
            $('#to').val(datetext);
        },
    });
    });
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        timeFormat:'HH:mm',
        use24hours: false,
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d1 = new Date();
            var d2 = new Date(d1);
            var addedhour=d2.setHours(d1.getHours()+4);

            // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d2.getHours()+": "+d2.getMinutes();
            $('#from').val(datetext);
        },
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 HTML 

     <link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <p>From:   <input type="text" id="to">  <div id="datepicker"></div> <p>To: <input type="text" id="from"><div id="datepicker1"></div>
    JQUERY 
    $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(datetext){

            var d = new Date(); // for now
            datetext = d.toString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt");
            //datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes();
            $('#to').val(datetext);
        },
    });
    });
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d1 = new Date();
            var d2 = new Date(d1);

            var addedhour=d2.setHours(d1.getHours()+4);

            // for now
            //datetext=datetext+" "+d2.getHours()+": "+d2.getMinutes();
            datetext = d2.toString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt");
            $('#from').val(datetext);
        },
    });
```

Check this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kepevu), You just need to add new js called date.js

Comment: Hi ,it is working for me thank you  how ever if i want to change date in To text box it is not changing  ,i need to change to customize.